# Async in Laravel 5.4 with Dingo API

Tags: php, api, asynchronous, laravel-5.4

I want my APIS made with DINGO can run ASYNC. Currently, my api is sync because when i try to request an API with sleep command and then I call another api, the second api just return value when firt request is passed over the sleep time. This is the code I used to test:

First api route:

```
 public function checkLongRunning(Request $request){
        $data = $request->all();
        if($data['check'] == 1){
           sleep(5);
            return response()->json(['error' => 'slept in 5 secs'], 500);
        }else{
            return response()->json(['error' => 'bad request'], 500);
        }
    }
```

Second api route:

```
public function checkLongRunning2(Request $request){
        $data = $request->all();
        if($data['check'] == 1){
            return response()->json(['error' => 'OK'], 500);
        }else{
            return response()->json(['error' => 'asd'], 500);
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway I can make my API (build with DINGO in Laravel 5.4) run ASYNC (can request another api when first api request are sleeping)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can response the request immediately after you've done everything you need (Auth, etc.), and you need a middleware attach to the endpoint so you can run the code after response been returned.

Example:

In api.php

```
$api->post('run', function () {
                        return response()->json([
                            "message" => "running"
                        ], 200);
                    })->middleware("postRun");
```

In "postRun" middleware

```
public function terminate($request, $response)
{
    sleep(2000) // place your code here.
}
```

BTW: You'll need to register the middleware.